# Karate - Not able to run dynamic scenario outline in a loop

Tags: karate

Here is my feature file , which just loads the json file and wants to iterate over the same

```
 Background:
 * def kittens = read('../json/test.json')
 Scenario Outline: cat name: <name>
 * print <name>
  Examples:
  | name |
  | kittens |
```

Here is the output

```
[
  {
    "name": "Bob"
  },
  {
    "name": "Wild"
  },
  {
    "name": "Nyan"
  },
  {
    "name": "Keyboard"
  },
  {
    "name": "LOL"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ceiling"
  }
]
```

As per my understanding this should run 7 times and give me individual  variable values , But its running only once and giving me full json as output .

Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: I tried in Karate 9 and karate 8 as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the list/array with a variable `name` in it, it will run only once as it interprets your entire json data as single variable `name`.

> you could have noted it printed the entire data in your test.json
>   once, as it acted as normal scenario outline.

You should pass the array directly as below to make it as dynamic scenario outline.

```
Feature: Dynamic Scenario Outline
 Background: 
  * def kittens = read('../json/test.json')
 Scenario Outline: cat name: <name> 
  * print <name> 
 Examples: 
  | kittens |
```

For dynamic scenario outline, the variables `<name>` will actually derived from your json, if there is key in your json as `"name"`. Not as the header of the list in `Examples:`.

Karate docs- [Dynamic Scenario Outline](https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline)

Comment: Tried but no scenario is getting executed , The following command is being used to run 
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="--plugin html:target/cucumber-html " -Dtest=RunAssertsOnProductionThreeRunner.java

Comment: @SourabhChapali your `Examples` table is wrong, please look carefully

Comment: Hmmm What is it :) . I copied and tried code suggested by @Babu still not working

Comment: @sourabhChapali the only thing that i missed was adding `Feature:` on top of background. This should work fine if your data in test.json read properly and the json data is exactly same as you mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

@Babu Sekaran. It was not priting cat names as used as above.
It was iterating number of times but not printing anything. Then i used * print '' means included quotes. then it started printing cat names.

```
Feature: Dynamic Scenario Outline
  Background:
    * def kittens = read('test.json')

  Scenario Outline: cat name: <name>
    * print '<name>'
       Examples:
         | kittens |
```