# Can I run example in scenario outline for n times?

Tags: karate

I want to run examples for `n` times , `n` is the length of data of `getHotelid`.

```
Feature: match rates from ds api to pricing api.

 Background:

 * url ''

 Scenario Outline: Calling production assert feature file.

 * def DbNew = Java.type('DbNew')
 * def dq = new DbNew()
 * def activeHotels = <ds_hotel_id>

 * def hotel_id = call read('StringConverter.js') { activeHotels:'#(activeHotels)'}

 * print hotel_id

Examples:
|dq.getHotelid()|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is look a like [Karate - Not able to run dynamic scenario outline in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54397780/8615449)

Your Examples should be as below,

```
Examples:
 |dq.getHotelid()|
```

please read this documentation : [Karate dynamic scenario](https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline)

Comment: one more thing, `dq.getHotelid()` should return an array of JSONs - else use `karate.map()` to transform it into one

Comment: @Babu tried to run both the above Example, but It failed , with the error : 
malani: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)

Comment: @varun as mentioned by peter `dq.getHotelid()` should return an array of JSON to qualify as a dynamic scenario outline. can you do `* def dsData = dq.getHotelid()` `* print dsData` and see whether you are getting array of data that has at least one json that has `ds_hotel_id` as key.

Comment: @VarunNahata the time has come to refer you to this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue